# How do closures have access to the outer function's variables even after the outer function returns?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

```
function celebrityName (firstName) {
     var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
     function lastName (theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
    }
    return lastName;
}
var mjName = celebrityName ("Michael");
mjName ("Jackson");
```

// This celebrity is Michael Jackson

Comment: That's just the *magic* of closures :-) The variables that are still referenced are not garbage-collected even when the outer function returns.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `nameIntro` is a `non-local variable` for the `lastName`-function. The variable `nameIntro` is stored in the `heap` instead of `stack` (in contrast to local variables, which are stored in the stack).

- [Non-local vartiable in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_variable)

A quote from the Wikipedia article:

> If the nested function is passed as an argument to a higher-order
>   function a closure needs to be built in order to locate the non-local
>   variables. If the nested function is returned as a result from its
>   outer function (or stored in a variable) the non-local variables will
>   no longer be available on the stack. They need to be heap allocated
>   instead, and their lifetime extend beyond the lifetime of the outer
>   function that declared and allocated them. This generally requires
>   garbage-collection.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the magic of closures. Different languages implement it differently. In JavaScript, you can imagine that a function object consists not only of code, but also a reference to an "environment" where it can look up non-local variables ("free variables"). When a function is created, this environment is set to the scope in which it was created. In the case of `lastName`, the scope in which it was created is the body of the `celebrityName` function.

Then, later when the `lastName` function executes and it needs to lookup `nameIntro` which is not a local variable, it looks in this environment that it kept. Note that this means even though the `celebrityName` function has returned, its scope (including the `nameIntro` variable) still exists and is accessible by the `lastName` function which has a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

The function that you have written can also be written as:

```
//Your Function
function celebrityName (firstName) {
    //Outer Variable
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
   //returned Function
   return function(theLastName) {
       //returned value of the function that is returned
       return nameIntro +firstName + " " + theLastName;
   }
}

//the returned function is mapped to mjName
var mjName = celebrityName ("Michael");
//Output of the returned function
mjName ("Jackson");
```

If you do not apply a closure then the scope of the outer variables will get lost when the garbage collector runs. Hence you would not be able to access it later.

However when a closure is applied and the outer variable is accessed by a "returning" function then a binding is maintained between them which does not allow the garbage collector to delete that. Hence you get the values

[Working Fiddle to demonstrate Closure](http://jsfiddle.net/c4svdx17/)